# JavaScript updating dropdown lists but can't seem to keep up - is something being cached?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to work this out for a long time now and have tried many avenues. Very simply, a group is picked from the drop down on the left. Those in the group appear in the *Assigned* col and those not in the group in the *Not Assigned* column.

[image]

I have the following `JavaScript` function that seems to work most of the time but when I make drop down selections quickly the resulting drop lists are incorrect. There is no pattern that I see but if I refresh the page it is fine again. If I make my changes to the drop down slowly it is fine.

The two parses system seems to work but maybe this method is causing problems. I encountered something like this before and was told the *var d = new Date();* line should fix any caching issue. Can anyone see why this might be happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkGroupList(chosenGroup) 
{
checkGroupListParses(chosenGroup, 'inGroup', 1);
checkGroupListParses(chosenGroup, 'notInGroup', 2);
}
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function checkGroupListParses(groupName, parseID, parseNo) 
{

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById(parseID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

var d = new Date();

searchString="http://website/getList.php?parse="+parseNo+"&groupName="+groupName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds();

xmlhttp.open("GET",searchString,true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to cancel the previous AJAX request in the event that it hasn't completed yet before a new one is issued.

Comment: Are you seeing the issue happen in any specific browser or version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to cancel the previous AJAX request in the event that it hasn't completed before a new one is issued (from a new drop down selection).

Imagine, your AJAX requests take 400ms to complete. You select an option from the drop-down, then select a new option within 250ms (you chose the wrong one the first time).

You are actually submitting two AJAX requests in this scenario before the first response is handled.

What you should do is abort the previous request in the event that you issue a new one.

Take a look at the [`abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Your code might look like the following:

```
var xmlhttp; //Move the scope of the XMLHttp object here. You might want to encapsulate all of this within an object if you want to have more than a single XMLHttpRequest object at times.

function checkGroupListParses(groupName, parseID, parseNo)
{
    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.abort();
        xmlhttp = null; //Get rid of the current request, and set the reference to null.
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById(parseID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    var d = new Date();

    searchString="http://website/getList.php?parse="+parseNo+"&groupName="+groupName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds();

    xmlhttp.open("GET",searchString,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I'd suggest at least wrapping that in a closure so that `xmlhttp` isn't at global scope. It would also be a good idea to encapsulate your requests, or use a library like `jQuery` if it is an option.